# How to get weight matrix after each iteration in Matlab Neural Network?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

By using train()/sim(), after each iteration the data in LW and IW matrices are overwritten and only the last one is accessible. Is there any way to get them while training (or testing)?

Comment: Did you find any method to compute the weight after each iteration?

Comment: @Paniz, nope. I was wondering about it while doing an assignment back then. Now I don't even use Matlab anymore...

Answer (score -1):

Use the same variable for saving each iteration result. It will automatically take the final answer.

Comment: Try to flesh out your answer a bit more, perhaps with an example of further explanations.